# Surface View squashed inside view pager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, surfaceview

I have a problem where I have a surface view inside a view pager. Everything renders fine until I press on one of the tabs. The view pager scrolls, but the page on the next screen is squashed.

[image]

[image]

If I exit the app and go back in it, the second page will render fine. Then if I press to go back to the first it squashes again.

I don't know at all what part of the layout is going wrong, and as far as I am aware, the actual height of the surface view is not changing, as when I use the .getHeight() method on the surface view it always returns the same value.

Here is my view pager class:

```
public class PendulumViewPager extends ViewPager {


public PendulumViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public PendulumViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

Here is the fragment being added to the view pager:

```
public class SurfacePanelFragment extends Fragment{

private int TYPE = 1;
private SurfacePanel panel;
public void setType(int type){
    TYPE = type;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_surface_panel, container, false);

    panel = view.findViewById(R.id.canvas);
    panel.setType(TYPE);
    return view;
}

public void startStopPendulum(ImageButton view){
    panel.startStop(view);
}

public void stopPendulum(){
    panel.stop();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(getUserVisibleHint()) {
        panel.delayStartThread();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getStopButton().setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp));
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    panel.terminate();
    super.onPause();
}

public void stopRendering(){
    panel.stopRendering();
}

public void startRendering(){
    panel.startRendering();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(panel != null) {
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            panel.delayStartThread();
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getStopButton().setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp));
            Log.i("WP", String.valueOf(panel.getHeight()));
        } else {
            panel.terminate();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PendulumViewPager pager;
private ArrayList<SurfacePanelFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<SurfacePanelFragment>(2);

private ImageButton stopButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    pager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SurfacePanelFragment frag = new SurfacePanelFragment();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    frag.setType(SurfacePanel.SINGLE_PENDULUM);

                    fragments.add(0, frag);
                    return frag;
                case 1:
                    frag.setType(SurfacePanel.DOUBLE_PENDULUM);
                    fragments.add(1, frag);
                    return frag;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: return "Single";
                case 1: return "Double";
                default: return "";
            }
        }
    });

    TabLayout pagerTabs = findViewById(R.id.pager_tabs);
    pagerTabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    pagerTabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startStopCurrentPendulum((ImageButton) view);
        }
    });

    ImageButton helpButton = findViewById(R.id.help_button);
    helpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startHelpActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void startStopCurrentPendulum(ImageButton view) {
    fragments.get(pager.getCurrentItem()).startStopPendulum(view);
}

public ImageButton getStopButton(){
    return stopButton;
}

private void startHelpActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the SurfacePanel class

```
public class SurfacePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public static final int SINGLE_PENDULUM = 1;
public static final int DOUBLE_PENDULUM = 2;

private int TYPE = 1;

private PendulumThread _thread;
private boolean needToStartThread = false;

private SurfaceHolder holder;

public SurfacePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(context, attrSet);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    Log.i("WP", String.valueOf(this.getHeight()));
    this.holder = surfaceHolder;
    if(needToStartThread){
        startThread();
        needToStartThread = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    if(_thread != null) {
        try {
            _thread.terminate();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.holder = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (_thread != null) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            _thread.click(event);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            _thread.updatePos(event);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            _thread.unclick();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void startStop(ImageView button) {
    if(_thread != null){
        if(_thread.isPRunning()){
            button.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp));
            _thread.pStop();
        }else{
            button.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp));
            _thread.pStart();
        }
    }
}

public void start(){
    if(_thread != null){
        _thread.pStart();
    }
}

public void stop(){
    if(_thread != null){
        _thread.pStop();
    }
}

public void stopRendering(){
    if(_thread != null){
        Log.i("WP", "A");
        _thread.stopRendering();
    }
}

public void startRendering(){
    if(_thread != null){
        Log.i("WP", "D");
        _thread.startRendering();
    }
}

public void terminate(){
    if(_thread != null){
        try {
            _thread.terminate();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void startThread(){
    if(_thread == null || !_thread.isAlive()) {
        switch (TYPE) {
            case SurfacePanel.SINGLE_PENDULUM:
                _thread = new SinglePendulumThread(holder, getWidth(), getHeight(), getContext());
                _thread.pStart();
                _thread.start();
                break;
            case SurfacePanel.DOUBLE_PENDULUM:
                _thread = new DoublePendulumThread(holder, getWidth(), getHeight(), getContext());
                _thread.pStart();
                _thread.start();
                break;
            default:
                _thread = new SinglePendulumThread(holder, getWidth(), getHeight(), getContext());
                _thread.pStart();
                _thread.start();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void delayStartThread(){
    if(holder == null) {
        needToStartThread = true;
    }else{
        startThread();
    }
}

public void setType(int type){
    TYPE = type;
}
```

And here is the surface panel fragment with the surface panel view in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.astarphysics.wikidpendulum.SurfacePanel
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the single pendulum thread

```
public class SinglePendulumThread extends PendulumThread{

private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Paint paint;
private int backgroundColor;
private int width;
private Context context;

private boolean clicked = false;

private static final double g = 9.81;
private final int RADIUS;

private int length;
private double theta = Math.PI/8;
private double thetaV = 0;

SinglePendulumThread(SurfaceHolder holder, int width, int height, Context context){
    this.holder = holder;
    this.context = context;

    int bobColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBob);
    int shadowColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.shadowColor);
    backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(bobColor);
    paint.setShadowLayer(5, -1, 2, shadowColor);

    this.width = width;
    RADIUS = dpToPx(20);
    length = dpToPx(200);
}

protected void update(){
    if(pRunning && !clicked) {
        thetaV += (-1 * g * Math.sin(theta)) / length;
        theta += thetaV * (40 * Math.pow(10, -2));
    }
}

protected void render(){
    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

    canvas.drawLine(width / 2, 0, (float) ((width / 2) + (length * Math.sin(theta))), (float) (length * Math.cos(theta)), paint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int) Math.round((width / 2) + (length * Math.sin(theta))), (int) Math.round(length * Math.cos(theta)), RADIUS, paint);

    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}

@Override
void click(MotionEvent e) {
    clicked = true;
    updatePos(e);
}

@Override
void updatePos(MotionEvent e){
    length = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt((Math.abs(e.getX()-(width/2))*Math.abs(e.getX()-(width/2)))+(e.getY()*e.getY())));
    theta = Integer.signum(Math.round((e.getX()-(width/2))))*Math.asin((Math.abs(e.getX()-(width/2))/length));
}

@Override
void unclick() {
    this.resetForPStart();
    clicked = false;
}

private void resetForPStart(){
    thetaV = 0;
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

and this is the double pendulum thread:

```
public class DoublePendulumThread extends PendulumThread {

private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Paint paint;
private int backgroundColor;
private int width;
private int height;
private Context context;

private boolean clicked1 = false;
private boolean clicked2 = false;

private final int RADIUS;
private final double m1 = 3;
private final double m2 = 3;
private static final double g = 9.81;

private double l1;
private double l2;

private double[] state = new double[4];
private double[] dydt = new double[4];
private double[] prev = new double[4];
private double[] midpt = new double[4];
private static final double h = 0.5;
private static final double DIMENSION = 4;
private static final double HALF = h/2;
private static final double THIRD = h/3;
private static final double SIXTH = h/6;


DoublePendulumThread(SurfaceHolder holder, int width, int height, Context context){
    this.holder = holder;
    this.context = context;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    //Setting sizes that require Context to be set
    RADIUS = dpToPx(20);
    l1 = dpToPx(150);
    l2 = dpToPx(150);
    state[0] = Math.PI/8;

    //Setting up paints for rendering on Canvas
    int bobColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBob);
    int shadowColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.shadowColor);
    backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(bobColor);
    paint.setShadowLayer(5, -1, 2, shadowColor);
}

/*
Evaluates derivatives for Runge-Kutta.
*/
private void loadDys(double[] y){
    dydt[0] = y[2]; //Theta1
    dydt[1] = y[3]; //Theta2

    dydt[2] = ( -1*g*(2*m1 + m2)*sin(y[0]) - m2*g*sin(y[0] - 2*y[1]) - 2*sin(y[0] - y[1])*m2*(y[3]*y[3]*l2 + y[2]*y[2]*l1*cos(y[0] - y[1])) ) / (l1*(2*m1 + m2 - m2*cos(2*y[0]-2*y[1])));
    dydt[3] = (2*sin(y[0] - y[1])*(y[2]*y[2]*l1*(m1+m2) + g*(m1+m2)*cos(y[0]) + y[3]*y[3]*l2*m2*cos(y[0]-y[1]))) / (l2*(2*m1 + m2 - m2*cos(2*y[0]-2*y[1])));
}

/*
Each time update is run one iteration of the Runge-Kutta method takes place, with time step h.
*/
protected void update(){
    if(pRunning && !clicked1 && !clicked2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
            midpt[i] = state[i];
            prev[i] = state[i];
        }

        loadDys(midpt);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
            state[i] += SIXTH * dydt[i];
            midpt[i] = prev[i] + HALF * dydt[i];
        }
        loadDys(midpt);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
            state[i] += THIRD * dydt[i];
            midpt[i] = prev[i] + HALF * dydt[i];
        }
        loadDys(midpt);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
            state[i] += THIRD * dydt[i];
            midpt[i] = prev[i] + h * dydt[i];
        }
        loadDys(midpt);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
            state[i] += SIXTH * dydt[i];
        }
    }else if(pRunning && clicked1) {
        state[3] += (-1 * g * Math.sin(state[1])) / l2;
        state[3] = state[3] * 0.9;
        state[1] += state[3] * (40 * Math.pow(10, -2));
    }
}

protected void render(){
    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

    canvas.drawLine(width / 2, height/4, (float) ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0]))), (float) (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0])), paint);
    canvas.drawLine((float) ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0]))), (float) (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0])), (float) ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])) + (l2 * Math.sin(state[1]))), (float) (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0]) + l2 * Math.cos(state[1])), paint);
    canvas.drawCircle((float) ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0]))), (float) (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0])), RADIUS, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle((float) ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])) + (l2 * Math.sin(state[1]))), (float) (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0]) + l2 * Math.cos(state[1])), RADIUS, paint);

    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}

void updatePos(MotionEvent e){
    if(clicked1){
        l1 = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(((e.getX()-(width/2))*(e.getX()-(width/2)))+((e.getY()-height/4)*(e.getY()-height/4))));
        if(e.getY() - height/4 < 0) {
            if (Math.round(e.getX() - width / 2) == 0) {
                state[0] = Math.PI;
            } else {
                state[0] = Integer.signum(Math.round((e.getX() - (width / 2)))) * Math.acos((Math.abs(e.getX() - (width / 2)) / l1)) + Integer.signum(Math.round((e.getX() - (width / 2)))) * Math.PI / 2;
            }
        }else if(Math.round(e.getY() - (height/4)) == 0){
            state[0] = Integer.signum(Math.round(e.getX() - (width/2))) * Math.PI / 2;
        }else{
            state[0] = Math.asin((e.getX()-(width/2))/l1);
        }
    }else if(clicked2){
        l2 = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(((e.getX()-((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0]))))*(e.getX()-((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])))))+((e.getY()-(height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0])))*(e.getY()-(height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0]))))));
        if(e.getY() - (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0])) < 0){
            if(Math.round(e.getX() - ((width/2) + l1*sin(state[0]))) == 0){
                state[1] = Math.PI;
            }else {
                state[1] = Integer.signum((int) Math.round((e.getX() - ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])))))) * Math.acos((Math.abs(e.getX() - ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])))) / l2)) + Integer.signum((int) Math.round((e.getX() - ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])))))) * Math.PI / 2;
            }
        }else if(Math.round(e.getY() - (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0]))) == 0) {
            state[1] = Integer.signum((int) Math.round(e.getX() - ((width/2) + l1*sin(state[0])))) * Math.PI / 2;
        }else{
            state[1] = Math.asin((e.getX()-((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0]))))/l2);
        }
    }
}

void click(MotionEvent e){
    if((e.getX() - ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])) + (l2 * Math.sin(state[1]))))*(e.getX() - ((width / 2) + (l1 * Math.sin(state[0])) + (l2 * Math.sin(state[1])))) + (e.getY() - (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0]) + l2 * Math.cos(state[1])))*(e.getY() - (height/4 + l1 * Math.cos(state[0]) + l2 * Math.cos(state[1]))) <= RADIUS*RADIUS){
        clicked2 = true;
    }else {
        clicked1 = true;
    }
    updatePos(e);
}

void unclick(){
    if(clicked1 || clicked2) {
        state[2] = 0;
        state[3] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
            dydt[i] = 0;
            midpt[i] = 0;
            prev[i] = 0;
        }
        clicked1 = false;
        clicked2 = false;
    }
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}

private static double sin(double x){
    return Math.sin(x);
}
private static double cos(double x){
    return Math.cos(x);
}
```

Here is the main activity in which the fragment is embedded into the view pager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/.   apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.astarphysics.wikidpendulum.MainActivity"
>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <com.astarphysics.wikidpendulum.PendulumViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

    </com.astarphysics.wikidpendulum.PendulumViewPager>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="144dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/stop_button"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_white_48dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/help_button"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_help_white_48dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/pager_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you think it is something else then I can add the code.

Thanks.

Comment: The single pendulum image seems to have some sort of scrim over the dark area. In the double pendulum image, this scrim only covers 1/2 of the dark area. What is that area covered by the scrim? The squashing may be related to the squashing of this scrim area. Use the layout inspector in Android Studio to take a look at those two images. You may also want to post code/XML that deals with that area.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The whole page is one surface view, the pendulum is free to take up the bottom half of the screen in the single example, it is just in the images it does not. I am not sure what you mean by there being a scrim.

Comment: Regarding the scrim: Look at the two-pendulum image. The top half of dark area with the pendulum has a lighter, frosted look to it. The bottom half is much darker. With the single pendulum, it is all black and all the same color. That is what I question. Post your `SurfacePanel ` class and the associated XML.

Comment: I have added the surface panel class and the layout file that has the surface view in. Is this the XML that you meant?

Comment: I guess you need to implement measure method ending with setMeasured*

Comment: What I am really trying to see is where you are drawing the actual images of the pendulums.

Comment: I have added the two threads. If it helps, this has only started to happen on the new android OS.

Comment: What is a measure method? @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: the method measure is called in the layout phase with two ints, wSpec and hSpec, that's the layout params provided by the parent, you get the values with the MeasureSpec class, after completing measurement you do setMeasuredWidth and setMeasuredHeight

Comment: I have overrided the onMeasure method and called setMeasuredDimension(wSpec, hSpec). Is this what you mean? @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: No, you must measure it properly, if you have fixed size then you must at least setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(wSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(hSpec))

Comment: So this just happens with Android 8.0? Do you see this on an emulator or a real device? Both?

Comment: Both real and emulator

Comment: In the XML the surface panel is set to have a width and height to match parent. I have added this to the surface panel class but the problem still remains. `@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));

    }` @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: I took look at where you are using `Canvas#drawCircle()` to draw the pendulum bobs. The method will only draw a circle and will not draw an oval like what you are seeing. So, my guess is that the canvas is being drawn correctly then it is being mapped into another view that is distorting the surface by changing the aspect ratio. You have posted the XML for `SurfacePanel`. It may be useful to see the XML in which the `RelativeLayout` parent of `SurfacePanel` is embedded. We would be looking for something that will change the aspect ratio.

Comment: I have added the main activity. The fragment for the surface view is embedded in the view pager. @Cheticamp

Comment: See if updating to the latest beta release of `ConstraintLayout` makes any difference. (It's 1.1.0-beta2.) Also, is your `CoordinatorLayout` working like you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing pages in the `ViewPager` does not force the fragments to go through their life cycles or cause a re-creation of the `SurfaceView`. Hitting `recents` or `home` and then going back to the app does cause the `SurfaceView`s to be recreated and that seems to correct the problem that you are seeing.

In case the problem is a subtle issue related to your layout, I suggest that you simplify it as much as possible. I have reworked the two main layouts to simplify them as you can see below. If you decide to go this route, you may need to change a few things in the main layout to get the sizing/positioning the way you want. You should not have to do any structural changes.

Something else to try if the above doesn't work is to force re-creation of a fragment whenever it is selected for API 26+. This will force a re-instantiation of the fragment and the layout and should correct the problem.

If the new layouts work, that would be best; if you have to do a re-creation upon tab selection, that is just a work-around. If you find out what the underlying problem is, please post it here. I would be interested in knowing what it is. Maybe another reader of this question can get to the bottom of it.

**pendulum_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/stop_button"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_white_48dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/help_button"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_help_white_48dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FF000000"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.example.viewpagerbase.PendulumViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/pager_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />
    </com.example.viewpagerbase.PendulumViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
    <com.example.viewpagerbase.MySurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is one way to force a new fragment when selected. There are other methods available online if you search for them.

Add the following to your `ViewPager` and call from each constructor. This will set up a page listener for API 26+. This listener will fire whenever a different page is selected.

```
private void init() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return;
    }
    addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            MainActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter adapter =
                // Your adapter name goes here
                ((MainActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter) getAdapter());
            adapter.invalidateFragment(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
        }
    });
}
```

Add the following to your adapter:

```
private List<SurfacePanelFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(PAGE_COUNT);

    @Override
    public SurfacePanelFragment getItem(int position) {
        if (fragments.get(position) == null) {
            fragments.set(position, SurfacePanelFragment.newInstance());
        }
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return (fragments.contains(object)) ? POSITION_UNCHANGED : POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void invalidateFragment(int position) {
        fragments.set(position, null);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
```

Comment: No difference, the surface view still appears squashed once you move to the double page or back to the single

Comment: According to the android device monitor layout view, the view pager, fragments and surface views all fill the space they should, even when I can see that it has been squashed on the emulator or device. @Cheticamp

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome That is all just unfortunate. :-( Try something that I just noticed. Get your app in its squashed state, then go to the [recents screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html) but don't change anything. Just tap on your app to bring it back. Does it look OK after you do this?

Comment: Yea that fixes the layout @Cheticamp

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome That's good, but it's not a solution. I also noticed that if "home" is pressed, it shows correctly (but briefly) before the home screen shows.

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed that too now that you point it out. Does android 'redo' the layout if you press home?

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome Don't know if it does or not. What does your `CoordinatorLayout` do for your app? Sorry for all the questions. I am not able to get `SurfaceView` to show on my API 26 emulator.

Comment: The `CoordinatorLayout` is just so the app bar can work with the view pager. I thought using a `CoordinatorLayout` was the general way to make a view pager with tabs. If not then I'm not sure it does anything else so to speak. And what do you mean by you can't get the `SurfaceView` to show?

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome `CoordinatorLayout` is not needed for `ViewPager`. It would be needed for the `AppBarLayout`, but `AppBarLayout` needs a scrolling sibling which your layout does not have. I am thinking that there is some complication in your XML that is causing API 26 to act oddly. There may be a way to simplify the layout so you don't lose its appearance or functionality while avoiding, what may be, a side effect. [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) is an example or something you could us. You would have to add your `Toolbar`.

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome As for not being able to display a `SurfaceVIew` that is just some issue between my emulator and my hardware. It is not related to this problem other than I can't test at all.

Comment: Still no luck. I'm not sure if this is something which should be the case, but when I try and specifically set the height of the root layout in the fragment to something like `300dp` the fragment still insists on taking up the whole screen in the app. I don't know if this is supposed to happen, or if it is linked to the problem?

Comment: Can I just ask one more question? What is the best way to force a fragment to recreate, and how would one do this for API 26 only?

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome Did you get something to work?

Comment: @BenjaminRogers-Newsome I am curious about what worked.

Comment: Forcing the layout layout to recreate got it working